# Can I disable SSLv3 in Internet Information Services?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ssl

I have Windows server 2012 R2 Standard. I need to disable SSLv3 in Internet Information Services.

Is it safe? If trying to disable SSLv3 and what type of issue will arise after this?

How about SSLv3?

I tried googling and wasn't able to find a concrete answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have screen short of registry for SSL3.0. I found three entry in registry, Cloud you please check and let me know, is this already disabled ?   http://prntscr.com/f8alzu

Answer (score 5):

> Is it safe?

It is not safe at all to keep SSLv3 running. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7568 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE

> what type of issue will arise after this

Well, clients that need this won't work anymore. Only you know what this will mean for your specific environment but in the vast majority of cases, it shouldn't have a noticeable impact as this affects only clients that are even more obsolete then SSLv3.

Answer (score 2):

Sven nailed the safety aspect.  You are extremely vulnerable by NOT disabling it.  That cannot be emphasized enough.

I searched for "windows server 2012 r2 disable sslv3" and Google provided this Microsoft Technet article as the 2nd link.  :)
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/3009008.aspx

The instructions are what I remember doing way back when.

Answer (score 1):

In order to Disable the SSL v3 Protocol, you must need to make changes on Server Registry.

See below Link;
https://cloudacademy.com/blog/how-to-fix-poodle-on-windows-server-2012/

Use IIS Crypto application. It would be the better option to manage the Server Registry setting.
https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto